# Define global variables to use inside components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-8

I have a Laravel 8 project, with vue-sweetalert2 installed.
I'd like to define the Toast behaviour once, and then call it inside my components.

By now I have this code:

**/js/components/Mypage.vue**

```
<script>
export default {
    data: function () {
        return { ... };
    },
    mounted() { ... },
    methods: {
        myMethod: function () {
            const Toast = this.$swal.mixin({
                toast: true,
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 2000,
                timerProgressBar: false,
            });
            axios
                .post("/api/something")
                .then((res) => {
                    Toast.fire({
                        icon: "success",
                        title: "Tessera rinnovata",
                    });
                });
...
</script>
```

This works fine, of course, but as you can see Toast is defined inside the method, and I cannot re-use it somewhere else.

I'd like to define it inside app.js (maybe) and than access it everywhere, but if I move the code inside app.js as is, I receive an error, that tells me that $swal is not defined.
I tried to use Swal instead of $swal... nothing changed.

**/js/app.js**

```
import VueSweetalert2 from "vue-sweetalert2";
import "sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css";

window.Vue = require("vue").default;
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueSweetalert2);

const Toast = $swal.mixin({
    toast: true,
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 2000,
    timerProgressBar: false,
});
```

So, how can I define the Toast once?

Comment: you can create a plugin for this kind of use case

Comment: I don't know how, I will take a look around

Comment: please look at this repo this is a demo for notification plugin which I createdhttps://github.com/bhumit070/notification-plugin

In this I am using vuetify's toast but you can replace it with sweet alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to setup the SweetAlert instance (`this.$swal` in your components) with initialization options. That could be done when installing the `vue-sweetalert` plugin. The second argument to `Vue.use()` is for the plugin options:

```js
// js/app.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueSweetAlert from 'vue-sweetalert2'

Vue.use(VueSweetAlert, {
  toast: true,
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 2000,
  timerProgressBar: false,
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vue-sweetalert2?file=src%2Fmain.js)